# How to get the mins and secs in UIPickerView as in figure?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview, uipicker

[image]

How can we achieve such type of selected values to be changed with **mins** and **secs** in UIPickerView???

Comment: Are you using the standard `UIPickerView`, or the `UIDatePicker` subclass?

Answer (score 4):

First, you use the `pickerView:viewForRow:inComponent:reusingView:` data source method to return the "00" label. This is actually a bit tricky, since pickerview will alter the frame of this view to fill the row. That means you have to embed your properly positioned view inside another view, and then return that container view instead.

As for the labels, those are simply `UILabel` objects that have been positioned correctly and added as subviews of the pickerview itself.

And to get them to update correctly, just change their titles in the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method.

This is exactly what `UIDatePicker` is doing.

Comment: can you please give steps to be followed with this two methods.. actually i tried to change name at didSelectRow.. but not succeeded..

Comment: Adding a UILabel in `pickerView:viewForRow:inComponent:reusingView:` method also creates the same problem i.e. it creates label on all the values instead of selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol` and `UIPickerViewDataSource Protocol`.

In method `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` just return needful title.

You can also add delegator on `valueChanged` event of `UIPickerView`. And each time your value changed you can reload all visible rows and set labels mins and secs at right positions.

Oooor you can just add subview with 2 `UILabel`s over the black line.

Oooor you can add subview with black gradient line with labels `mins` and `secs`.

Then using method : `- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component` you can set appropriate width of your columns.

Comment: I have thought of adding UILabels as we are doing in UITableView in creating cell... but in this case how to achieve that i am not getting..

Comment: Why you cannot just add to your `UIPickerView` subview? `UIPickerView *picker; [picker addSubview:labelWithMinAnsSec];`

Comment: Adding a UILabel in `pickerView:viewForRow:inComponent:reusingView:` method also creates the same problem i.e. it creates label on all the values instead of selected row.

Comment: No, you should add label when you are creating UIPickerView, not in its methods.

Comment: Adding label?? how to do that?? I have tried adding label using addSubview method... still not successful.....

Comment: Please, show me your code that adds `UILabel` to `UIPickerView`